# Add multiple Cells to TableRow

Tags: asp.net, listview, tablerow, findcontrol, tablecell

Solution to add 2 cells to a asp:Table TableRow. I'm pulling the data for the table from a database and removing the comma separated items with the string function.

```
protected void listView_Bids(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        TextBox TextBoxHighlights = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2");
        Table FindHighlightTable = (Table)e.Item.FindControl("bidHighlightTable");

        if (TextBoxHighlights != null)
        {

            string benefits = (TextBoxHighlights.Text.ToString());

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            int i = 0;

            string[] words = benefits.Split(',');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {

                if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    row = new TableRow();
                }
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Text = word.ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);

                i++;

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    FindHighlightTable.Rows.Add(row);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the  that I have in my ListView:

```
<asp:Table ID="bidHighlightTable" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered bid-highlight-table" runat="server">
   <asp:TableRow runat="server">
      <asp:TableCell runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TableCell runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at an alternative control which can also provide a standard html table as the output.

I would suggest in your case looking at a DataList (another asp.net control).

With this control you can set the **RepeatColumns** property which in your case you would set to 2. This would mean your content will fill both columns when populating.

A DataList control renders as a standard HTML table the same in which you are trying to achieve with your sample code.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. I friend of mine actually helped me out with this one and I've edited my post to show the solution.